# Is it possible to check if a tmp table exist on a linked server?

Tags: t-sql, linked-server

I have been trying to write code to check if a Tmp table ##Tmp1 exist on a linked server 135.282.123.12,
but the one I tried is currently not working.
PLEASE SEE BELOW.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('[135.282.123.12].database.dbo.##Tmp1') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    PRINT 'YES'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  PRINT 'NO'
END
```

I hope I could get your assistance.

PLEASE NOTE: The server IP is just a made up one for this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `OBJECT_ID` works on remote instances, but could check `tempdb`:

```sql
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [135.282.123.12].tempdb.sys.tables WHERE [name] = N'##GlobalTemporaryTable')
    PRINT N'YES';
ELSE
    PRINT N'No';
```

Comment: Hi @Larnu - I tried your method and it worked, thank you so much for assisting regarding this. Appreciate the help.

Comment: You're welcome, @WimpieNorman . If this did answer the question, please consider marking it as the solution, so that future readers know the answer was helpful (and that the question was answered correctly). Thanks!

Comment: I was unable to make it as the answer it has a cool down right after a thread has been created, but I have marked it now. Once again thanks for the help, you saved me a lot of time.